# What does foreach($vars as $a=>$var){} mean?

Tags: php, foreach

I ran into this code, `foreach($vars as $a=>$var){ // some process here}` and I wonder what is the difference when using `foreach($vars as $var){ // some process here}` ? Thanks.

Comment: C'mon. http://php.net/foreach

Comment: Agreed with @ceejayoz . Php Documentation is relatively easy to understand.

Comment: aw. Really? Is that necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `=>` represents the relationship between a key and value. You can imagine that the key points `=>` to the value.

**EDIT:**

`foreach` can be used in two ways:

> 1.Iterating over values:

Each time round the loop, the variable is set to the next value in the array.

Eg:

```
$fruitColours = array(
    "Banana" => "Yellow",
    "Apple"  => "Green",
    "Plum"   => "Purple",
);

foreach ($fruitColours as $colour)
{
    echo "$colour<br/>\n";
}

?>
```

The above will display:

```
Yellow
Green
Purple
```

Only the values of the array are displayed.

> 2.Iterating over keys and values

Each time round the loop, the variables are set to the next key and value pair.

Eg:

```
$fruitColours = array(
    "Banana" => "Yellow",
    "Apple"  => "Green",
    "Plum"   => "Purple",
);

foreach ($fruitColours as $fruit => $colour)
{
    echo "$fruit is $colour<br/>\n";
}

?>
```

The above will display:

```
Banana is Yellow
Apple is Green
Plum is Purple
```

Check the [php foreach documentation](http://in.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for further reference

Answer (score 2):

```
$vars = array(
  'key1'=>'something',
  'key2'=>'test',
);

foreach($vars as $key=>$value){
  echo "$key:$value" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

will output:

```
key1:something
key2:test
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach($vars as $a=>$var){ // some process here}`
iterates through an array (`$vars` in this case). In each iteration, `$a` is attributed the key of the actual array item, and `$var` the respective value.

`foreach($vars as $var){ // some process here}` does the same as above, but with this one, only the value of each array item is returned. The key value is not returned.

Check [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in the php manual for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with `foreach($vars as $var){ // some process here}` you only get the value, while with `foreach($vars as $a=>$var){ // some process here}` you also get its key.

```
    $data = array('NAME' => 'Tom', 'AGE' => 20);

foreach($data as $var){
    echo $var . "\n";
}
echo "\n";
foreach($data as $key => $var){
        echo $key .': '. $var . "\n";
}
```

will output

```
Tom
20

NAME: Tom
AGE: 20
```